# Finding $g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ DNE, but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I am working on exercises from *Calculus* by Spivak.

> Consider the following properties:
>
> - $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L\neq 0$
> - $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=\infty$
>
> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function with **neither** of these properties. Show that there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)$ does exist.

**My attempt:** If $f(x)$ does not have either property, then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)|<\epsilon$. In other words, we can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily small by decreasing $|x|$. If $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=\infty$ (does not exist). However, $f(x)g(x)=1$ so $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=1$.

**My concerns:**

- I'm not sure if there is another case other than $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ that I am not considering.
- Overall logic of the proof.

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ has neither of those properties. Same for $\frac1x\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: A very important case is when $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist and you are ignoring this possibility.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will revise my proof.

Comment: f(x) = tan(1/x) : g(x) = cot(1/x) then f(x)g(x) = 1 - well that's my try, not sure though, be interested to know wht you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x_n)=0$ for some sequence $x_n \to 0$ define $g(x_n)=1$ for all $n$ and $g(x)=0$ for ll other $x$. If this is not the case then $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x$ near $0$ and you can take $g(x)=\frac 1 {f(x)}$. To show that $\lim g(x)$ does not exist assume that it exists and consider the case when the limit is $0$ and the one where the limit is not $0$.

Comment: I also do not understand how stating $f(x_n)=0$ for some sequence $x_n\to 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ not existing.

Comment: We want to make sure that $\lim g(x)$ does not exist. Prove by contradiction. If it exists and the limit is $0$ then we get $\lim |f(x)| =\infty$ which is not permitted. If $\lim g(x) =M \neq 0$ then $\lim f(x) =\frac 1 M \neq 0$ which is also prohibited.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much.